# Firebase/Crashlytics crash report not uploaded

Tags: xcode, crashlytics

Getting an error with the new [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.0.0-beta.1 in the log with -FIRDebugEnabled

*[Firebase/Crashlytics] Skipping report with id 'xxx' this run of the app because Organization ID was nil. Report will upload once settings are download successfully*

I did download GoogleService-Info.plist, there is no Organization ID there.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm having the same issue. @Nimeton

Comment: Sorry I'm way late but the problem went away with a newer version

Answer (score 2):

I have same error, then I open ticket with Firebase support and they send me next reply:

> The second thing I noticed from the logs is that the Firebase SDK
> version being used is a bit old "6.18.0", the latest version is
> "7.0.0" If running "pod install" gives you the same version, you could
> try running the command "pod update" or "pod install --repo-update" to
> get the latest version.

This recent update **Version 7.0.0 - October 26, 2020** works for me.
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_700_-_october_26_2020